# Mongoid as_json causes document to delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

When running the following query, MongoDB mysteriously issues a delete command and removes the object that as_json was run on. `to_json` has the same effect.

```
Stream.first.as_json
```

**MongoDB log**

```
database=integration collection=streams selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 62.9890ms

MOPED: 54.237.57.2:10996 DELETE       database=integration collection=streams selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('55087e6e436c611d42410000')} flags=[:remove_first]
```

**Environment**

RAILS 4.2, Mongoid 4.0.2 and MongoDB 3.0.0

**Stream Model**

```
class Stream

include Mongoid::Document

field :stream_identifier, type: String
field :cover, type: String
field :caption, type: String
field :location, type: String
field :place, type: String
field :watchers_count, type: Integer
field :comments_count, type: Integer
field :likes_count, type: Integer
field :restreams_count, type: Integer
field :activities, type: Array
field :influencers, type: Array
field :encores, type: String
field :cover_images, type: Array
field :status, type: String
field :end_time, type: Integer
field :tweet_id, type: String
field :fans, type: Array
field :likes, type: String
field :delete, type: String
field :playlist, type: String
field :restreams, type: String
field :comments, type: String
field :watchers, type: String

alias_attribute :likesCount, :likes_count
alias_attribute :coverImages, :cover_images
alias_attribute :commentsCount, :comments_count
alias_attribute :watchersCount, :watchers_count
alias_attribute :restreamsCount, :restreams_count
alias_attribute :endTime, :end_time
alias_attribute :tweetId, :tweet_id

embeds_one :broadcaster
has_one :feed

def update_stream
    UpdateStreamStatus.perform_async(self.stream_identifier)
end
end
```

**BroadcastModel**

```
class Broadcaster
include Mongoid::Document
field :identifier, type: String
field :name, type: String
field :display_name, type: String
field :profile, type: String
field :image, type: String

alias_attribute :displayName, :display_name

embedded_in :stream
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a field called `delete` in your `Stream`:

```
field :delete, type: String
```

For each field (`f`) in your model (`m`), both `as_json` and `to_json` will call `m.f`. That means that every `as_json` or `to_json` call will end up calling `m.delete`. Presumably that's calling Mongoid's `delete` method and that deletes the document from MongoDB (without calling callbacks).

I'd recommend renaming your `delete` field to something that doesn't conflict with Mongoid's methods.

Comment: Bravo! Bravo! Wow...I can't believe there is inflection based from a field name...